# Django middleware is causing internal server error in server but runs in debug mode

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I have created a custom middleware in Django with following files:

1. models.py with one model.
2. views.py with following code:

   ```
   class UserRequestClass(object):
       def process_request(self, request):
           try:
               user_request = GivenModel()
               user_request.request_parameters = request
               user_request.save()
           except:
               pass
           return None
   ```
3. I have added the application to installed_apps.
4. I have added the
   middleware class to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

The code runs well with python manage.py runserver on my local computer as well as server.
But when I run the save code with Gunicorn and Nginx, it is giving Internal Server error. The error is gone after removing the class from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Am I messing up with something here?

Comment: The error is simply "Internal Server Error". Nothing is shown even when Debug=True.

Comment: Do you have non-ascii characters anywhere in your code?

Comment: No. I am simply saving the request into database.

Comment: I'm not just asking this. I have come across an annoying bug, where when using non-ascii characters (and declaring a utf-8 encoding at the top of my scripts), sometimes I will get an `internal server error` even in debug mode and the traceback will blame bad encoding (even when the issue is syntax or something else that is irrelevant). I have no idea why this issue exists, but I have encountered it

Comment: Try setting `Debug=False` and look into the Nginx and Gunicorn error log. What does the traceback say?

Comment: Nginx log has stored nothing. How can I keep logs with Gunicorn?

Comment: This is pretty old and I hope your problem was solved. However, In django - you can only access the internal request data once per request. This means, you either access it in middleware or the view where you process the request. I did a workaround to this and got a workable solution. Try searching on these lines or wait while I upload a gist containing the code that I used for my Middleware class.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SehgalDivij/1ca5c647c710a2c3a0397bce5ec1c1b4
Try This.